# Can i check the iPhone specific kind?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know it may sound like a strange question but i dont want to fall on this .
I have read that if i use something that is not documented i can get rejected by Apple ,
To get iphone kind i use :

```
//get iphone kind
-(NSString*) machineName
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Can i use this ?
The `[UIDevice device]` cant do this ,is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say this isn't documented? Type "uname" into the search field of the Documentation tab of the Xcode Organizer and you will be shown the man page for `uname`.

There are many C functions that are fully documented through "man pages". These are all perfectly safe to use in an iOS app.

I use the code you posted in several apps in the App Store. It's not an issue.